# How to add tab bar controller to the subview in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, subview

Is there any way to add a tab bar controller to a subview of the iPad app? Below is the screen that shows what I am talking about:
[image]

When I try to add tab bar controller to the view its showing on the whole width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the autoresizing mask of the view of the tab bar controller, it will assume the full size of its superview.

Either manually edit the frame or autolayout constraints of the view of the tab bar controller (when  instantiating the tab bar controller or in viewDidLayoutSubviews) or add it to a child view that has  a frame equal to the grey area in your image.

If you set the frame when instantiating the tab bar controller, be sure to change the autoresizingMask property of the tab bar's view so that it doesn't have flexible width or flexible right margin.

Comment: Thank you foir your answer. My question for now is: How to add this to the childView?

Comment: You are already adding it now, aren't you? Just specify [childView addSubview:myTabBarController.view] instead of [self.view addSubview:myTabBarController.view]. Also make sure to read the docs on the UIViewController method **addChildViewController**. If this doesn't help, please post some code of how you got it set up right now.